# Embedded YouTube player video quality parameter

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

Please help me to figure out which parameter and its values I have to use to setup HD quality of the YouTube video (or any quality I need).

Under https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters I see nothing useful...

I use this code basically

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/r5nnlG3hEfU?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0
```

For example I need 240, or 720 how do I pass this parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the parameter `vq=hd720` will make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be &hd=1 but since last week ~10/5/12 Google seemed to have blocked the use of the HD parameter and now only the user can manually set HD from the player controls.

It sucks, my site http://goproheroes.com relies on this HD param being set or not. I can't find any official word on the change, I'm guessing it's to save bandwidth costs but I'd like to see an official statement regarding it.

Edit:

OK I've got 720p to work again by falling all the way back to their oldest legacy player (AS2) using: &version=2 in the embed code

Comment: Thanks!!At least you found something!! +1

Comment: It looks like someone from Google has seen this reply, it's disabled on the AS2 legacy player now :(